# Does this regex have one or two groups? "^\\s*(.*?)\\s+-\\s+'(.*)'\\s*$"

Tags: java, regex

Does this `regex` have one or two groups?

I'm trying to access the `bookTitle` using the second group but getting an error:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*(.*?)\\s+-\\s+'(.*)'\\s*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("William Faulkner - 'Light In August'");
String author = matcher.group(1).trim();
String bookTitle = matcher.group(2).trim();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are TWO groups but the error is because nothing is being done with the matcher.
There is a IllegalStateException being thrown when trying to get the first group at `matcher.group(1)`.
One of the methods `matches`, `lookingAt` or `find` must be called.
This should do:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*(.*?)\\s+-\\s+'(.*)'\\s*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("William Faulkner - 'Light In August'");
if (matcher.matches()) {
    String author = matcher.group(1).trim();
    String bookTitle = matcher.group(2).trim();
    ...
} else {
    // not matched, what now?
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Two groups -- `'` is not a special character in regexes.  What is the error you're getting?

Also, they **ARE NOT** zero-based.  From the javadoc:

> Group zero denotes the entire pattern,
>   so the expression m.group(0) is
>   equivalent to m.group().

Answer (score 2):

Add one of following before you ask groups.

```
 matcher.find();
 matcher.maches();
```

How this works:

> A matcher is created from a pattern by
>   invoking the pattern's matcher method.
>   Once created, a matcher can be used to
>   perform three different kinds of match
>   operations:
>
> The **matches** method attempts to match
>   the entire input sequence against the
>   pattern.
>
> The **lookingAt** method attempts to match
>   the input sequence, starting at the
>   beginning, against the pattern.
>
> The **find** method scans the input
>   sequence looking for the next
>   subsequence that matches the pattern.

Source: [Java Api](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

I personally recommend you remove multiple whitespace first, then split and trim - viola simple, tested, and works.

Try this:

```
    String s = "William          Faulkner - 'Light In August'";
    String o[] = s.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").split("-");
    String author = o[0].trim();
    String bookTitle = o[1].trim();
```

If you would:

```
    System.out.println(author);
    System.out.println(bookTitle);
```

Then output would be:

```
William Faulkner
'Light In August'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Matcher class seems to be lazy: it actually postpones the evaluation until the matches() method is called. Try this instead

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*(.*)\\s+-\\s+'(.*)'\\s*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("William Faulkner - 'Light In August'");

if (matcher.matches()) {
    String author = matcher.group(1).trim();
    String bookTitle = matcher.group(2).trim();

    System.out.println(author + " / " + bookTitle);
}
else {
   System.out.println("No match!");
}
```

You also might want to change the groups to (.+) to make sure that you will not get books with empty authors/titles.